# Building a kotlin native module using Buck build tool

Tags: kotlin, build-tools, buck, kotlin-native

On [kotlin section](https://buckbuild.com/rule/kotlin_library.html) of buck documentation there is no information about [kotlin native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native-overview.html) projects. I guess there is no support, at least I wasn't able to build a native project using Buck.

Does anyone know if it is possible to build a kotlin native module using buck build tool?

Comment: Everything is possible with `genrule`. Looks like kotlin-native differs too much to be used as drop-in replacement both for java-based tooling and for c compiler.